# How to set environment variable that are used in different tests files in Jenkins

Tags: typescript, jenkins, playwright

In my `random.test.ts` file I am using env variable:

```
test.beforeAll(async () => {
    new testBase.BaseTest(page).login(process.env.EMAIL, process.env.PASSWORD);
})
```

I would like to run my tests using Jenkins, but I don't know how to pass my locally defined env variables to `Dockerfile`. At the moment, it looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { 
    docker { 
      image 'mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.17.2-focal'
    } 
  stages {
    stage('install playwright') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          npm i -D @playwright/test
          npx playwright install
        '''
      }
    }
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          npx playwright test
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to add it to Dokerfile as environment,

```
  }
  environment {
    EMAIL = 'random'
  }
```

but I'm not so sure how should I update `random.test.ts` file. Maybe somebody has suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need to edit `random.test.ts` once you inject the environment variables to the container I suppose they will be pickedup by your script. Two ways to do this. One is the method you mentioned defining a environment block or else you can pass as environment args.

```
agent { 
  docker { 
    image 'mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.17.2-focal'
    args "-e EMAIL='something' -e PASSWORD='something'"
  } 
}
```